# Translating multiple translationIds using AngularJS's translation directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I'm using PascalPrecht's AngularJS Translation module.

---

```
{
    APP.WELCOME: 'Welcome',
    APP.USER: 'user'
}
```

`<span translate>{{'APP.WELCOME'}}</span> <span translate>{{'APP.USER'}}</span>`

Works fine. It outputs `Welcome user`.

---

Now, is it possible to combine two translationId's in one element? I've tried multiple things:

```
<span translate>{{'APP.WELCOME'}} {{'APP.USER'}}</span>

<span translate>{{'APP.WELCOME APP.USER'}}</span>

<span translate>{{'APP.WELCOME' + 'APP.USER'}}</span>

<span translate>{{'APP.WELCOME'; 'APP.USER'}}</span>

<span translate>{{['APP.WELCOME','APP.USER']}}</span>
```

but nothings seems to work.

Any suggestions? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using two double brackets elements inside a single `<span>`, and translate as a `$filter`:

```
<span>{{'APP.WELCOME' | translate }} {{ 'APP.USER' | translate }}</span>
```

It should work...

Comment: In your translations file you wrote `APP.HELLO`, instead of `APP.WELCOME`... if it's not a typo in the question, that could be the cause... :-)

Comment: Fixed. Thanks. That was just a typo in the question. In my production I use different translationId's :)

Comment: And it's not working? Strange... To tell you the truth, in my project I use `<span>{{ 'text1' | translate }} {{ 'text2' | translate }}</span>` constructs, from `pascalprecht.translate` (as a `$filter`), and it works just fine... Updated my answer to reflect this suggestion...

Comment: Never thought of that.. Thanks!